# No audio on an HP dm4

Tags: sound, alsa

I just got a new laptop, HP dm4, and I'm having problems getting the audio to work properly on it.

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=7b697a35465a9f7236fb94deb9ff97fa65e55489

I tried to edit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf and added:
option snd-hda-intel model=ref

this caused the audio to work, but it's muffled. I'm wondering if anybody knows what would be the correct options to get this POS to work.

Answer (score 1):

if anybody else faces this problem and gets here, what solved the problem for me was to edit `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`and add the following line:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```